# Execute a file using a pattern as the filename

Tags: regex, delphi, pattern-matching

As part of my application I need to give the users the ability to execute files (videos) from my application, but the problem is that the application does not store a list of these files anywhere in the application itself and the only infomation that is known about the file is the directory it's located in and that it must match a specific pattern, which looks like this: `* - Ep[0-99] - *` where the `*` character represents any string, integer, unicode character, etc of any length and `Ep` & `-` are string literals and finally, the `[0-99]` is any integer value between 0 and 99.

This sounds like a perfect job for regular expressions, but the problem is regular expressions require a string to match against ahead of time before a match can be found and as previously stated, the application does not store this string anywhere so using RegEx would not work unless I first used something like the `FindFirst` function to search the directory the files are located in and then iterate over it, loading each of the files names in a variable that RegEx can match against, but I would rather avoid doing things like this if there is an better alternative available.

I have also looked into the `MatchesMask` function to accomplish this task, but it suffers from the same issue that using regular expressions does so I would appreciate some advice or an alternative to the method I already mentioned above.

Comment: No avoiding reading file names. You can use TDirectory.GetFiles instead of FindFirst/Next.. (which internally use FindFirst, ..).

Comment: `TDirectory.GetFiles()` iterates the entire directory, (inefficiently) allocating and then returning an array of filenames that it found. Calling `Find(First|Next)()` directly lets you process the filenames while iterating. So it really depends on what you need to do with the files, how many files are present, how much memory you are willing to use, etc. Whoever designed the `System.IOUtils` unit did not do a very good job with it.

Comment: Yup, TDirectory.GetFiles is a little convenient to use (although it uses nasty TStringDynArray, eiugh) but the perf is horrid. Any veteran programmer would have recoiled at its implementation so presumably the code review policy at Emba is lax.

Answer (score 1):

There's no getting away from enumerating the contents of the directory. If you must avoid that, for reasons unknown, then your only remaining option is to guess the filenames. If you wish to find them all then you'd need to try every possible filename that matches your pattern. That is not tractable. There are far too many.

Which takes us back to `FindFirst` or some other directory enumeration scheme. Personally I would use `FindFirst` directly. It is simple to call, and efficient. In pseudo-code:

```
retval := FindFirst(TPath.Combine(dir, '*'), 
  faAnyFile and not faDirectory, searchRec);
if retval = 0 then
  try
    repeat
      filename := TPath.Combine(dir, searchRec.Name);
      if MatchesRegex(filename) then
        DoStuff(filename);
    until FindNext(searchRec) <> 0;
  finally
    FindClose(searchRec);
  end;
```

Comment: You can do this processing when your application first starts to create list of matching files, then set up notification for changes to the directory (such as a file being added/deleted or renamed) and evaluate whether you need to modify the list.  MSDN on changenotification:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762120.aspx and if you have JVCL installed:  http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:JvChangeNotify.pas or you could use this component:  http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/directory-watch/

Comment: @user if you trust change notifications, which aren't reliable

Comment: Can't speak to the reliability of change notification, can say I use it and never had any issue.

Comment: @user it's documented as being unreliable

Comment: Can you add link to "documented as being unreliable"  Is that by MS itself, or are you referring to the one person adding a comment to the MSDN link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60272/discussion-between-user582118-and-david-heffernan).